# How can I permanently hide the "protect your privacy" message in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

How can I make this message disappear and never show?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the message by switching to "simple HTML" (or plain text) email view. Go to `view > message body as > Simple HTML`.
Please note that external content such as images doesn't load and formatting can appear as slightly broken as a result.

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Thunderbird/comments/4o0x3v/remote_content_notice/d49j090/)